# Why large sample size makes ANOVA less affected by normality assumption violation?

Tags: anova, sample-size, f-distribution

One of the assumptions of ANOVA, and basically any parametric hypothesis test, is that the population (or each population group) should be normally distributed. But we learn in most stats classes that the violation of this assumption becomes less relevant (or less affected) as the sample size gets large.

In **t-tests** for example, when the population normality assumption is violated, the test statistic for basically any kind of t-test will not exactly follow the t-distribution, making the test results less accurate. However, when the sample sizes become larger and larger, the test statistic for any t-test approaches the Z-statistic (which follows the standard normal distribution) due to the Central Limit Theorem and Law of Large Numbers, which means that the test results will be less biased. This is pretty much the intuition I have on t-tests for why the violation of the population normality assumption can be tolerated to some extent as the sample sizes become large.

Now, I am looking for a similar kind of intuition for **ANOVA**. Most online resources do state that when sample sizes get large, the normality assumption violation is not much of a problem. However, no matter where and how much I search, I cannot find any reason as to why this is the case.

What I know about ANOVA is that the test statistic MST/MSE will follow the F-distribution when all the ANOVA assumptions are exactly met, and if the null hypothesis is true. So obviously, when the normality assumption is violated, it is possible to infer that the test statistic MST/MSE will **deviate** from the F-distribution, making the p-values and the F-values more biased.

In this case, assuming that the normality assumption is violated, why does the ANOVA test statistic MST/MSE become a less biased measure as the sample sizes for each group get larger? All I can think of at the moment is that it must be related to the CLT and LLN, but that's about it.

Does the test statistic MST/MSE approach the F-distribution again from the previously deviated distribution as the sample size for each group gets large? Or, is there another reason MST/MSE becomes less biased as the sample sizes get large?

To anyone who has a clear understanding of this, I would really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Note the shift in your query from *robust* to *reliability*. Though related, these are not the same thing. Reliability refers to consistency, robust or robustness to the strength of a statistical model, tests, and procedures. Look them up to confirm. Given that, do you still have a question?

Comment: This kind of robustness is greatly misunderstood in practice.  The CLT is a _limit theorem_ which has questionable actionability in finite sample sizes.  I have an example where for a one-sample problem the CLT was not accurate enough for $n=50,000$.  But there is a more general problem.  The robustness statisticians speak of is robustness related to type I assertion probability $\alpha$.  Failure of the normality or equal variance assumptions can do major damage to power ($1 - \beta$) even for huge sample sizes.

Comment: @MikeHunter  Thanks for clarifying those terms. I think robustness is the word I have been meaning to say (I edited the post slightly). The question that I want answered is, why do professors and other sources say that the violation of the normality assumption in ANOVA is not much of an issue when sample sizes are large? This statement is over many places but I have never seen any explanation for it - I want to understand "why" this is the case, especially in relation to the test statistic of the ANOVA **MST/MSE**.

Comment: Professors who say that are just wrong.  They have drunk the central limit theorem koolaid and they are ignoring statistical power.  Type I assertion probability $\alpha$ is much easier to contain than $\beta$.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Well, if violation of the assumption becomes a huge problem even for large sample sizes how do we do ANOVA in real world data analysis then? Most data in the real world will inevitably violate the assumptions to some extent right? Especially the population normality assumption. Most dataset never exactly follow the normal distribution. In that case, what logic do we use to justify the use of ANOVA if we can't use "large sample size" as the main argument in ANOVA?

Comment: Simple.  Quit using parametric methods when nonparametric methods (1) test more general ordering hypotheses, (2) do not assume a distribution, (3) are robust to outliers, (4) are 0.95 as efficient as parametric methods when their assumptions hold, and (5) the efficiency can be must greater than 1.0 when assumptions of parametric methods do not hold.  The Kruskal-Wallis test is the nonparametric counterpart to regular ANOVA, and the proportional odds model generalizes the K-W test to allow for adjustment variables, longitudinal data, etc.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes, that's an alternative. But my question is, do the hundreds of existing research papers and data analysis that previously used ANOVA as their test all essentially assume that the data are normally distributed? Your comment sounds like we should never use ANOVA because in real life we can never exactly meet the normality assumption... I'm pretty sure I saw many examples that used ANOVA for their research and justified its use by stating that the sample size was very large without ever mentioning anything about the normality of the distribution, and this is where I'm confused.

Comment: The sample size justification is insufficient.  Parametric ANOVA has been used far too frequently.  Were nonparametric methods to be inefficient that would be another matter.  I especially distrust parametric analyses where the authors made a conclusion from large P-values, as imperfectly transformed data can render the test insensitive.  The amount of non-normal "contamination" that has to be present before the parametric methods quit working is astonishingly low.  The large sample size excuse need to be sent to the dustbins of statistical history.

Comment: See the first example from https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar.html where adding a point that makes the means **more** separated makes the p-value **larger**.

Comment: *Do the hundreds of existing research papers and data analysis that previously used ANOVA as their test all essentially assume that the data are normally distributed? * Yes! You seem to be assuming an equivalently high or uniform level of statistical sophistication across these pubs. That's a mistake. Elsewhere, Frank Harrell has noted the illogic in using metrics assuming normality and symmetric distribution on hugely asymmetric info, an incontrovertible and completely ignored criticism.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I see! Then can I take it that if the normality assumption is violated, the ANOVA test may show biased results (possible deviations between true and reported significance level / p-value, etc) even if the sample sizes are large? In other words, unlike other parametric tests like the t-test where the normality assumption violation becomes less important as sample size gets large, large sample sizes do not solve the issues that arise from normality assumption violation in the case of **ANOVA** and therefore the normality assumption here is essential regardless of sample size?

Comment: Eventually the same limit theorems kick in for ANOVA as for the t-test (it all can be generalized as regression modeling of various kinds). However, the sentiment seems to be that such theorems apply at our convenience, rather than requiring a careful assessment of how large of a sample size is required to be “close enough” (so it’s just assumed to be “close enough” when that is a convenient assumption instead of having a basis in reality). Enough examples exist where the convergence theorems are inadequate that flexible methods are appealing for the finite sample sizes of real empirical work.

Comment: Again, be sure to not concentrate just on type I assertion probability accuracy.  The "kicking in" may completely miss out regarding power.  For example if you should have taken logs but didn't the SD that goes into a $t$-test may be meaningless.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the answer. Actually my original inquiry is directly related to your comment: **How/WHY** does the CLT impact ANOVA such that very large samples that pass the certain threshold makes ANOVA passable even when the population is not normally distributed? As I've mentioned on the post I've sort of understood the intuition for the t-test, but I can't find out about ANOVA. Could you elaborate on **how** or **why** the CLT eventually "kicks in" for ANOVA? Which part of the test statistic does it impact when sample sizes get large and why does that lead to CLT "kicking in" for ANOVA?